# Why does my PhotoImage doesn't shows up in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

it's my first question here.

I use tkinter with python3.9 for displaying an image, a flag of which country it shows up on the window

```
# gets the img flag
flag = PhotoImage(file=flagsFolder+countryList[rand_label]) # the path is "D:\Images\Flags of the world" + "XXXX.gif"

# creates the img Label
flagLabel = Label(frame, image=flag)
flagLabel.place(x=window_width/2, y=200, anchor='center')
```

So, when I try to display the image, it shows me this:

[image: this]

A flag should be here instead of the white image.

Why isn't it showing up?

Comment: Does `flagsFolder` have a backslash at the end?

Comment: Try changing it to a png file instead of a gif. I agree with @martineau. You should join paths using the os module

Comment: Probably because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091), but since you didn't post a [mcve] it's hard to say for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I messed around a bit and found out a solution.

I had to use ImageTk from Pillow so:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
```

Then, instead of creating a Label for my image, I made a Canvas:

```
# notice how I used ImageTk.PhotoImage instead of the basic PhotoImage from Tkinter
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='filename.png')

# creates the img Canvas
imgCanvas = Canvas(frame)
imgCanvas.place(x=window_width/2, y=200, anchor='center', width=img.width(), height=img.height())
imgCanvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)

imgCanvas.image = img # now the image displays perfectly :D
```

The final result:

[image]